# How to add new stages/rename a stage in MLflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, mlflow

I was doing some experiments with MLflow using Python 3.7, and I was wondering if I can rename a stage or add a new one to the pre-existing

> None | Staging | Production | Archived

Currently, I registered a model obtained from an experiment, but I would like to add multiple developing phases. I read the [docs](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/model-registry.html#concepts) concerning that part, but the only thing I've found is the following:

> Each distinct model version can be assigned one stage at any given
> time. MLflow provides predefined stages for common use-cases such as
> Staging, Production or Archived. You can transition a model version
> from one stage to another stage.

Comment: https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/2165
closed for similar  request for now, waiting for new mlflow version to support your ask

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible [but has been submitted as a feature request](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/3686).

As a workaround you could [add custom tags](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.html#mlflow.set_tag) to your registered models and apply some logic in your code regarding these tags, but on the MLflow Model Registry they will still appear altogether on the same pre-defined stages.